# MySQL, How to reuse calculated data in groups

Tags: mysql, variables, group-by

I would like to reuse calculated data for a group:

```
# what I would like to obtain:
#_timeslice              _count     _min        _max        _delta
# 2017-11-01T00:00:00Z     4          90         140          50 
# 2017-11-01T00:15:00Z     3         100         160          60 
# 2017-11-01T00:30:00Z     2         110         130          20 
# 2017-11-01T00:45:00Z     4          80         150          70 

CREATE TABLE `test-table`
    (`date_time` datetime, `val1` float);

INSERT INTO `test-table`
    (`date_time`,         `val1`)
VALUES

    ('2017-11-01 00:00:00', 140),  # first 15 min
    ('2017-11-01 00:01:00', 110),
    ('2017-11-01 00:02:05',  90),
    ('2017-11-01 00:14:00', 100),

    ('2017-11-01 00:15:00', 100),  # second 15 min
    ('2017-11-01 00:16:00', 160),
    ('2017-11-01 00:28:00', 120),

    ('2017-11-01 00:30:00', 110),  # third 15 min
    ('2017-11-01 00:44:59', 130),

    ('2017-11-01 00:50:00', 120),  # fourth 15 min 
    ('2017-11-01 00:55:00', 150),
    ('2017-11-01 00:57:00', 100),
    ('2017-11-01 00:58:00',  80)
;

SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date_time`)/900)*900) AS _timeslice,
    COUNT(*) AS _count,
    min(`val1`) as _min,
    max(`val1`) as _max,
    max(`val1`) - min(`val1`) as _delta  # obvious but inefficient because they are recalculated    
FROM `test-table`
GROUP BY _timeslice;
```

SQLFiddle is here: [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bad89/9)

The **_delta** is inefficient because max and min are recalculated again.

Is there another syntax to avoid this second useless calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that variables in this context are not possible. 
In MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual, chapter 9.4 *User-Defined Variables*:

> "In a SELECT statement, each select expression is evaluated only when
>   sent to the client. This means that in a HAVING, GROUP BY, or ORDER BY
>   clause, referring to a variable that is assigned a value in the select
>   expression list does not work as expected."

A possible solution (less readable) is to use sub-queries:

```
SELECT 
       subquery.*, 
       subquery._max - subquery._min as _delta
FROM
       (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date_time`)/900)*900) AS _timeslice,
            COUNT(*) AS _count,
            min(`val1`) as _min,
            max(`val1`) as _max,
        FROM `test-table`
        GROUP BY _timeslice) AS subquery;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the cause for bad performance. MySQL is smart enough not to do unnecessary work.
More likely is, that you're missing an index on `(date_time, val1)`.

In your sqlfiddle, click on "View execution plan", you'll see that you're doing a full table scan.

Then have a look at this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52b318/1/0). It uses the index I created perfectly.

```
create index idx_tt_dt_val1 on `test-table`(`date_time`, `val1`);
```

Here's a manual page, that might also interest you: [GROUP BY Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html)

Comment: I thought the same, @fancyPants, but it looks like that when a more complex function than min/max is used this optimization is lost. This is the fiddle I am using: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52b318/4  Here I select the first and last element of each group and calculate their delta. Checking the timings on a set of data (a few million lines) I see that the two functions used for _delta are recalculated even if they have been copy&pasted and should be available from before.

_first and _last take some ~ 45s; adding the _delta is an extra 45 seconds.